# How to use global css style sheet includes with GatsbyJS

Tags: webpack, gatsby

By default, GatsbyJS is pushing the use of css modules and custom css-in-js libraries like [glamorous](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glamorous) and [typography](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typography)

Unfortunately, I am porting an existing site to GatsbyJS that uses traditional global style sheets. The effort to convert all the existing HTML-CSS instrumentation to CSS modules is a chore.

My current hack is to update the GatsbyJS `html.js` and add a

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.old.css" />`

To the header. I have `style.old.css` living in `/public` this, however, gets wiped out when a build is run.

I was hoping there would be a plugin to support this but seems the Gatsby team is discouraging global CSS which is understandable for fresh projects.

I attempted to write a plugin to add this but found limited resources on how to write a "style plugin".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close!

Instead of placing `style.old.css` in `/public`, place it in `/layouts`. Then, simply import it into `/layouts/index.js` like this:

`import './style.old.css'`

When you start a new gatsby project (`gatsby new project-name`), you'll notice an `index.css` file in the `/layouts` folder, which is imported into `layouts/index.js` by default. Just follow this example to add your own global stylesheets.

In general, you should not place anything in `/public` directly. If you'd like static files to end up in the `/public` folder, create a `/static` folder and place them there (Gatsby will copy any files in `/static` to `/public` for you).

Comment: This is a nice and clean solution. If you only need some rules from the stylesheet and don't want to bundle the whole thing in in you can also use a solution like https://github.com/glortho/styled-import (note: i am the author!)